# Is there a word that means holding your gun low?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there a word that means holding your gun (rifle, handgun, machine gun, etc.) low? By that holding a gun under the belt in order to "aim inaccurately", "shoot" a gun towards any direction (back, upward, front, left, right, bottom). I see some people do it. It's mostly some cowboys firing the gun low to shoot faster. I am not sure if there's a word for it.

Comment: You already posted this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/224689/what-does-fire-from-the-hip-means/224690#224690.  Is there a reason your original question wasn't sufficient, or are you trying to ask something substantially different?

Comment: The reason a gun is held near the hip – shoot from the hip – is not so that it can be fired inaccurately (although it may be) but to fire as soon as the gun has been removed from its belt holster. That is, sooner than it can be fired by raising it to eye level and taking careful aim. I guess that with practice it can be accurate.

Comment: In gaming terms it might also be called *spray-and-pray*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often hear the phrase "**hold your gun at the ready**" which is mostly used at exactly such moments. The police man for instance may be holding it in his gun belt unstrapped and ready to be unholstered any second. Or there could be a different situation.